# 2 times drop-down menu selection in a row with RSelenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape this [website](https://www.searates.com/). I got a problem with text fields because text fields and drop-down menus combined. The site does not allow to enter the names of cities directly. For example, I only want to take the port pointers (ex: Port of Shanghai, China), firstly, I must enter "Shanghai, China", and need to click the first option, then need to click "Port of Shanghai, China". (actually, ports are the second option). With the following codes, I can select the country name but not the port.

```
> remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value ='from')$sendKeysToElement(list("Shanghai, China"))$clickElement()
> remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", value = "#from-autocomplete > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1)")$clickElement()
> remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", value = "#from-autocomplete > div > div > div > div.fvlk5rSgKI--Xo4zMn3an > div:nth-child(2)")$clickElement()
```

But in the second selection for port names (3rd line), the port name has been erased from the text field.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, ayth and welcome to SQA stack exchange. Giving only a link to a site is not enough info. Please provide part of the HTML DOM where you element is. As far as I see from you code it looks like the classes that you want to select are dynamic and you have to find some static value to select. Also using ">" in you css selector is highly breakable so instead design your selectors to be flexible to the changes. Google for css selectors reference w3schools. PS: from the website that you've provided the first and the second options are not selectable(bug in the site) when type "Shanghai, China"

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, this "drop-downs menu" are more appropriate to be called "suggestion results".
So here is my answer and hope it works because I don't have RSelenium to test it. I added intentionally some sleep just to give enough time for the components to load (delete the sleeps if it works without them after you test it). I also modified the css selectors to be less breakable:

```
> remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value ='from')$sendKeysToElement(list("Shanghai, China"))$clickElement()
> Sys.sleep(2)  
> remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", value = "#from-autocomplete [tabindex="0"]")$clickElement()
> Sys.sleep(2)  
> remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", value = "#from-autocomplete [tabindex="1"]")$clickElement()
```

Comment: I tested but the same problem occurs again - for port selection, the text has been erased from the field. An interesting nuance is that when we run the first code, **Error: attempt to apply non-function** this error occurs, but the code works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the website's JavaScript is interfering with the second click event, which is erasing the previously entered value. To overcome this issue, you can try the following approach:

1. Use the `sendKeysToElement` method to enter the city name and wait for a while using the `Sys.sleep` function or `remote_driver$client$setTimeout` method to give the website's JavaScript enough time to process the input and populate the dropdown menu.
2. Use the `findElements` method to get a list of all the options available in the dropdown menu.
3. Use a loop to iterate through the list of options and check for the desired option, for example the port name.
4. When the desired option is found, use the `clickElement` method to select it.

Here is an example code:

```
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value ='from')$sendKeysToElement(list("Shanghai, China"))
Sys.sleep(5)
options <- remote_driver$findElements(using = "css", value = "#from-autocomplete > div > div > div > div")
for(option in options) {
  if(grepl("Port of Shanghai, China", option$getElementText())) {
    option$clickElement()
    break
  }
}
```

The `Sys.sleep` function is just used to wait for the dropdown menu to appear. The actual wait time might be different based on your system and internet speed, so you may need to adjust it accordingly.